# Displaying users that have not logged in since a supplied date

Tags: bash, grep

I am on a Unix box, and I am trying to create a script that the user enters a date ( month and day) eg. Nov 15. and it will search 'last' and display the users that have not logged in since the date provided, how can I do this?

So if their are 20 users in last

```
user1
user2
etc...
```

And 19 logged in last on the 10th of November, and 1 logged in on the 12th of November.

if i use the script to search Nov 11 it will display the users name that logged in on the 12th of November.

any ideas? 
thanks

Comment: Your first paragraph states that you want "users that have not logged in since the date provided" your last paragraph says "it will display the users name that logged in on the 12th, if I give it the 11th" Which is it? Users that have not logged in since the date provided or users that have logged in since the date provided? Also what do you mean "Search 'last'" ?

Comment: i mean the command last on unix that displays the times everybody last logged in. this is what i will be using to work out when the last logins was.

Comment: and it can be any date it is just an example

Comment: sample data, filter criteria (in this case a date), expected output helps to disambiguate problem definitions. Consider updating your question to include a sample filter and the expected output, given your sample input. Good luck!

Comment: You can do it with `who /var/log/wtmp` and then parse the results by date with either `awk` or with process substitution in a shell script using `date`. (of course you will have to also parse /etc/passwd for a list of users)

Comment: Check your [`last` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/last.1.html) for the `--since` option

Comment: Checking who logged in last will only show the list of users who logged in. If you are interested in who didn't login, you will need access to the set of users, usually retrieved by running `getent passwd`. Once you have both, you will need to get the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

While I suppose that you could use the 'last' command (with lots of date-related-coding) it might be simpler to use 'lastlog' - If you have to use a 'date', then you will need to convert that to 'days'.

```
Usage: lastlog [options]

Options:
  -b, --before DAYS             print only lastlog records older than DAYS
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -t, --time DAYS               print only lastlog records more recent than DAYS
  -u, --user LOGIN              print lastlog record of the specified LOGIN
```

i.e.

```
lastlog -b 10 # show logins older than 10 days - will be a large list  

lastlog -b 10 | egrep -ve "Never logged in" # or build an exclusion list
```

:)
Dale